# Get custom JQGrid JSON data in gridComplete method

Tags: json, jqgrid, customization

Here is a typical JQGrid JSON response:

```
{
  "page":1,
  "records":537,
  "rows":[..],
  "rowCount":10,
  "total":54
}
```

Along with this, I want to send additional custom data.  For example, I'd like to send the database time of the last search so that I can lazy-reload my grid whenever changes have occurred since then.  Here is how I would like to send that data:

```
{
  //Custom name-value pairs:
  "nameValues":{"lastSearchTime":"2011/09/01:14:14:56"},

  //Normal JSON data:
  "page":1,
  "records":537,
  "rows":[..],
  "rowCount":10,
  "total":54
}
```

The problem is that JQGrid swallows up the JSON response rather than forwarding it to the `gridComplete` method.  In other words, params is undefined in the following function:

```
function myGridComplete (params){
   //params is undefined!

   var JSONResponse = ?;//I need your help here!!!

   globalGridVariables.lastSearchTime = JSONResponse.nameValues.lastSearchTime;

   //Rest of grid complete method
   ..
}
```

Please let me know if there is a way to get access to the JSON response object in the `gridComplete` method, or if there is another supported way to add custom data to a JSON response.

Thanks much!

**Note:**  I don't want to send this as a hidden column, because that would be inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `loadComplete` instead of `gridComplete`. The `loadComplete` event has one parameter (for example `data`) which represent the full data from the server response inclusive all of your extensions.

Alternative you can rename the `nameValues` to `userdata` and use `$('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData')` to get the value. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848815/how-to-read-userdata-in-jqgrid/3849513#3849513) for more information.

Moreover you can consider to use more [HTTP caching](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885658/jqgrid-data-stored-in-browser-cache/3885956#3885956) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704886/jqgrid-caching-the-grid-data/3722532#3722532)) for the aims which you described in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [beforeProcessing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) that has the deserialized response and gets active before gridComplete and loadComplete.

For example:

```
beforeProcessing: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            myArray = data.rows;
                        }
```

And just to make it more clearer from the documentation:

Below is the execution order of the events when a ajax request is made

1. beforeRequest
2. loadBeforeSend
3. serializeGridData
4. loadError
5. beforeProcessing
6. gridComplete
7. loadComplete