# C# MVC2 Jqgrid - what is the correct way to do server side paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities, jqgrid, paging

I have a jqgrid where the database table has a few thousand rows, but the jqrid shows only 15 at a time.

It should be displaying very quickly (it doesnt take long to query 15 rows).  But instead it takes 10 - 20 seconds, which indicates to that it is retrieving the entire table each time.

The grid is defined like this:

```
$("#Products").jqGrid({
url: url, mtype: "get", datatype: "json", jsonReader: {
    root: "Rows", page: "Page", total: "Total", records: "Records", repeatitems: false,
    userdata: "UserData",id: "Id"},
colNames: ["Product Id","Product Code", ... etc ],
colModel: [{ name: "Id", ... etc}],
viewrecords: true, height: 400, width: 800, pager: $("#jqgPager"),
rowNum: 15, rowList: [50, 100, 200], 
autowidth: true, multiselect: false
```

And the server side (MVC2 action) does this:

```
var model = (from p in products
    select new
    {
    p.Id, p.ProductCode, p.ProductDescription,
    AllocatedQty = p.WarehouseProducts.Sum(wp => wp.AllocatedQuantity),
    QtyOnHand = p.WarehouseProducts.Sum(wp => wp.OnHandQuantity)
    }).AsQueryable();

    JsonResult json = Json(model.ToGridData(
        page, rows, orderBy, "", 
        new[] { "Id", "ProductCode", "ProductDescription", "AllocatedQty", "QtyOnHand" }),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And finally the model.ToGridData extension method does this:

```
var data =_service.GetAll(); 
var page = data.Skip((index) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
list.Add(page.AsEnumerable);
```

And I'm a bit lost as to where the problem lies:

- Have I set the jqgrid paging options incorrectly?
- Have I written bad Linq that pulls all rows regardless? 
  eg does the Sum() cause all rows to be read?
- Have I done the .Skip().Take() incorrectly?
- Have I missed something else entirely?

EDIT

When comparing my code to the example posted by Oleg I can see that I do things in this order:

1. getAll
2. select model fields
3. page

Wheras Olegs sample seems to be in this order:

1. getAll
2. page
3. select model fields

So I've changed to this much simpler implementation:

```
public ActionResult GetProductList(int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord, 
string searchOper, string searchField, string searchString)
{
        List<Product> products = _productService.GetAllProducts();
        int totalRecords = products.Count();

        var pagedData = products.Skip((page > 0 ? page - 1 : 0) * rows).Take(rows);

        var model = (from p in pagedData
                    select new
                    {
                        p.Id, p.ProductCode, p.ProductDescription,
                        Barcode = string.Empty, UnitOfMeasure = string.Empty,
                        p.PackSize, AllocatedQty = string.Empty,
                        QtyOnHand = string.Empty }).ToList();

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = page, records = totalRecords,
            page = (totalRecords + rows - 1) / rows, rows = model
        };

        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

However this has a new problem:

```
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type
'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_FA935D3899E2...
```

The only difference I can see now with Oleg's sample is that his getAll returns `IQueryable` where mine is just `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post more full code. The `model.ToGridData` is not defined in the current code for example. How you caclulate `index` from the imput patrameters and so on are also unclear. Only having `model.ToGridData()` one can say whether the output which your program produce are correspond to the `jsonReader` which you define.

I recommend you to look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078592/sortable-jqgrid-using-linq-to-mysql-dblinq-and-dynamic-linq-orderby-doesnt-w/4079121#4079121) old answer, where both paging and sorting are used. In [one more answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169384/how-can-i-bind-my-view-model-to-a-jqgrid) you will find more references to code examples.

Comment: Thanks, I've edit my question based on the first example.  Btw in your example you have `total = ` repeated twice in the `var jsonData = ` statement.

Comment: @JK: Probably you should use `var jsonData = new {..., rows = model };` instead of `var jsonData = new {..., rows = pagedData };`? Currently you don't use `model` variable which you only assign. If it not solve your problem you should write in what line you receive the exception.

Comment: Yes of course, my mistake... `rows = model` is what I wanted.  Its returning the data now, I need to check it is all working properly and do some timing tests etc..

Comment: Thanks Oleg - deployed fix to the live server, and load time reduced from 10 seconds to 1.

Comment: @JK: Good news! The users will be happy.