# C# Entity Framework + Linq - how do you speed up a slow query?

Tags: c#, linq, performance, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

This is a question related to [C# MVC2 Jqgrid - what is the correct way to do server side paging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189888/c-mvc2-jqgrid-what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-server-side-paging) where I asked and found how to improve the performance for a query on a table with 2000 or so rows. The performance was improved from 10 seconds to 1 second.

Now I'm trying to perform the exact same query where the table has 20,000 rows - and the query takes 30 seconds.  How can I improve it further? 20 thousand rows is still not a huge number at all.

Some possible ideas I have are:

- It can be improved by de-normalizing to remove joins and sums
- Make a view and query that instead of querying and joining the table
- Don't query the whole table, make the user select some filter first (eg an A | B | C .. etc filter)
- Add more indexes to the tables
- Something else?

This is the MVC action that takes 30 seconds for 20 thousand rows: (the parameters are supplied by jqgrid, where sidx = which sort column, and sord = the sort order)

```
public ActionResult GetProductList(int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord, 
string searchOper, string searchField, string searchString)
{
    if (sidx == "Id") { sidx = "ProductCode"; }
    var pagedData = _productService.GetPaged(sidx, sord, page, rows);
    var model = (from p in pagedData.Page<Product>()
            select new
            {
                p.Id, p.ProductCode, p.ProductDescription,
                Barcode = p.Barcode ?? string.Empty, 
                UnitOfMeasure = p.UnitOfMeasure != null ? p.UnitOfMeasure.Name : "",
                p.PackSize, 
                AllocatedQty = p.WarehouseProducts.Sum(wp => wp.AllocatedQuantity),
                QtyOnHand = p.WarehouseProducts.Sum(wp => wp.OnHandQuantity)
            });

    var jsonData = new
    {
        Total = pagedData.TotalPages, Page = pagedData.PageNumber,
        Records = pagedData.RecordCount, Rows = model
    };

    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

ProductService.GetPaged() calls ProductRepository.GetPaged which calls genericRepository.GetPaged() which does this:

```
public ListPage GetPaged(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    var list = GetQuery().OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord);
    int totalRecords = list.Count();

    var listPage = new ListPage
    {
        TotalPages = (totalRecords + rows - 1) / rows,
        PageNumber = page,
        RecordCount = totalRecords,
    };

    listPage.SetPageData(list
        .Skip((page > 0 ? page - 1 : 0) * rows)
        .Take(rows).AsQueryable());

    return listPage;
}
```

The .OrderBy() clause uses LinqExtensions so that I can pass in a string instead of a predicate - could this be slowing it down?

And finally ListPage is just a class for conveniently wrapping up the properties that jqgrid needs for paging:

```
public class ListPage
{
    private IQueryable _data;
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }

    public void SetPageData<T>(IQueryable<T> data) 
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Page<T>()
    {
        return (IQueryable<T>)_data;
    }
}
```

GetQuery is:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQuery()
{
    return ObjectSet.AsQueryable();
}
```

The custom .OrderBy method consists of these two methods:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
    string ordering, params object[] values)
{
    return (IQueryable<T>)OrderBy((IQueryable)source, ordering, values);
}

public static IQueryable OrderBy(this IQueryable source, string ordering, 
    params object[] values)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (ordering == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ordering");
    ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] {
        Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "") };
    ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(parameters, ordering, values);
    IEnumerable<DynamicOrdering> orderings = parser.ParseOrdering();
    Expression queryExpr = source.Expression;
    string methodAsc = "OrderBy";
    string methodDesc = "OrderByDescending";
    foreach (DynamicOrdering o in orderings)
    {
        queryExpr = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), o.Ascending ? methodAsc : methodDesc,
            new Type[] { source.ElementType, o.Selector.Type },
            queryExpr, Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(o.Selector, parameters)));
        methodAsc = "ThenBy";
        methodDesc = "ThenByDescending";
    }
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(queryExpr);
}
```

Comment: With the edit, I'm very confused as to how it jumps back to generic-based code, when that OrderBy uses non-generic code... can you clarify? am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you are asking - this `OrderBy()` is an extension method defined in another class.

Comment: Well, `GetQuery()` is going to return `IQueryable<T>` (generic); `GetQuery().OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)` (using the method you show) will be `IQueryable` (non-generic). AFAIK there is no `Skip(...)` etc *defined* for non-generic... not sure how that is going to be working?

Comment: Also - silly question, but is there an *index* defined for the sort you are trying to do? Could this be as simple as adding an index to the database column?

Comment: Good question about the generic vs non generic. I dont know, but when I hover the mouse over the .OrderBy it says it is `(extension) IQuerable<T>` and it also says that `var list ` is `IQueryable<T>`.  There is no index on the ProductCode column - it is nvarchar(500) so too large for an index as I understand it.

Comment: @JK - the index will surely help, but I don't think that the one you have posted is the right `OrderBy` method; you might want to try [F12] (Go To Definition)

Comment: Ah right F12 shows how it goes from generic to non to back again. I will edit the question again (how many edits am I allowed?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bit that concerns me is:

```
.Take(rows).AsQueryable()
```

the fact that you needed to add `AsQueryable()` suggests to me that it is currently `IEnumerable<T>`, meaning you could be doing the paging at the wrong end of the query (bringing back *way* too much data over the network). Without `GetQuery()` and the custom `OrderBy()` it is hard to be sure - but as always, the first thing to do is to profile the query via a trace. See what query is executed and what data is returned. [EFProf](http://efprof.com/) might make this easy, but a SQL trace is probably sufficient.

Comment: +1 - also there is a little known `ObjectQuery<T>` ext meth called `.ToTraceString()` which shows the SQL query to be executed. Very handy for logging.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, `GetQuery()` is a one liner: `return ObjectSet.AsQueryable();` .  I will edit and add the code for OrderBy() - I don't know where it was sourced from, possibly here: linqextensions.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JK - to be honest, it might suffice for you to simply check if the code works if you remove the `.AsQueryable()`

Comment: @JK - perhaps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby/233505#233505) ?

Comment: It still compiles without `AsQueryable`.  I will do a timing test, it will take a few mins to get it all setup and done.

Comment: @JK - it is more the actual query that goes to the DB that will be interesting here.

Comment: Where can I add the `.ToTraceString()`?  I don't have any variables of type `ObjectQuery<T>`

Comment: @RPM1984 can you advise on the above comment at all?

Comment: It still works very quickly on the 2k list without the `AsQueryable()`.  But there's something wrong with my test database with 20k products.  I will have to reimport the CSV before I can see how long it takes.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - `ObjectQuery<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>`. `ObjectQuery<T>` is EF-specific, and since he's working with EF, he can do an explicit cast to `ObjectQuery<T>`: `var trace = ((ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString()`. He's doing `ObjectSet.AsQueryable()`. If he *didn't* do the `AsQueryable`, and did some LINQ operations on `ObjectSet`, the result would be an `ObjectQuery<T>`. Am i wrong?

Comment: Where is the best place to put `ToTraceString`?  I added it to `GetPaged` directly after the `GetQuery.OrderBy()`.  The trace just said `SELECT Id, ProductCode, .... FROM Products ORDER BY ProductCode`.  I do notice that it selected all fields even though I only use a few of them.

Comment: So it worked. Well i guess i *wasnt* wrong. :) The best place to put it is right before you execute the query (`.ToList(), `SingleOrDefault()`, etc). I would do it in your `GetPaged` method: `var trace = ((ObjectQuery)GetQuery().OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)).ToTraceString();`

Comment: CSV import has only processed 6500 rows (its very slow!), but all indications are good so far - taking just 1 second to load the page.  The only change I've made is to remove the `AsQueryable()`.  I think that was only there because originally ListPage.Page was a different type (I forget what now).

Comment: Well, that was a pretty good answer - accepted with thanks. 22k records are now paging in just 1 second.  It was pretty sharp of you to pick out the `AsQuerable()` problem amongst all that code - straight to the correct answer.