# jqGrid filter or search by date not working client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 page.  On it, I have a table which I turn into a jqGrid using JSON data from an ajax call.  The grid has the following setup:

```
myGrid = $('#myGrid');
myGrid.jqGrid({
    caption: 'My Grid',
    datatype: 'local',
    data: data.rows,
    height: 250,
    pager: '#myPager',
    viewrecords: true,
    colModel: [
        ...,
        {
            label: 'blah',
            name: 'blah',
            align: 'left',
            sortable: true,
            editable: false,
            width: 85,
            formatter: 'date',
            sorttype: 'date',
            datefmt: 'm/d/Y',
            formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' }
        },
        ...
    ]
});

// turn on filter toolbar
myGrid.filterToolbar();
```

data.rows is returned from the ajax call.  This works in all ways except one.  I can paginate client-side, sort client side, and search by every field except the one I show the colModel for.  This 'blah' field is a date field, and it displays the dates correctly, in mm/dd/yyyy format.  However, when I type in something like 11/17/2010 into the toolbar and press enter, the search returns 0 records.

So I dug deep into the jqGrid code, and here's what it generates before it searches:

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"blah","op":"bw","data":"11/17/2010"}]}
```

Eventually, when it goes through every row and it evaluates the operation on the field, the eval(m) && p.push(this) line, m is this:

```
(String(this.blah).substr(0,10) == String("11/17/2010"))
```

Basically, it looks to me like it's not recognizing that the field is a date.  It calls parse instead of parseDate.  Anybody have any ideas how to fix this?  I know searching server side is easy, I can just pass that string, parse it, and bam.  But I'd like to stay client side if I can.  I was able to duplicate this in some of the samples that Oleg and Tom put up, so it's either an issue or I'm missing something in the configuration...

Comment: By the way jqGrid can make AJAX call for you, so the usage of `data.rows` will be not needed. See some links from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835957/jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-calling-ajax-enabled-web-service/2836817#2836817, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169384/how-can-i-bind-my-view-model-to-a-jqgrid/4169848#4169848 and http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/rest-support/#p21762. I can continue with the links...

Comment: Actually, I had to wrap the creation of the grid inside my ajax call.  The reason for that is that I have to call GridUnload() because I'm dynamically updating my drop down filter in the filter toolbar.  I looked through the documentation and couldn't find something like trigger('reloadToolbar').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find your question interesting so +1 from me to your question. Because you posted the line

```
(String(this.blah).substr(0,10) == String("11/17/2010"))
```

used in `eval` during the local searching I suppose you spend much time to understand how the local searching are implemented. Because you see that the line above (see `(String(this.blah).substr(0,10) ...`) is not what should be done (the value of `String(this.blah)` will be "2010-11-17" instead of "11/17/2010"), you can overwrite the corresponding function of jqGrid (the function `_getStr` inside of `$.jgrid.from`) and fix the problem in the way.

Some time ago I spend much time to prepare the corresponding [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomSearch.htm), which demonstrates this technique. The demo was prepared as [the answer in trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/searching-on-text-field-with-accentued-chars-on-local-datas/#p21529). In the question one wanted to find strings like `'bénevise'` in case of searching for `'benevise'`. So one have to implement really custom local searching. I hope that the information will be enough for you to fix the problem which you describe.

**UPDATED**: It seems to me that I have found a much more simple workaround. You should just define `searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','ne']}` for the `'blah'` column having the data. Then `"bw"` (begin with) will not used for the column. The "equal to" and "not equal to" operations work correctly in the local searching.

**UPDATED 2**: [Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDate.htm) is the working example where I use `sopt` option.

Comment: Ok, I worked through the example and it works if I change my source data.  I noticed the data you're using has dates defined like "2007-09-01".  My data had: new Date("2007-09-01").  The reason is my source data is coming from ASP.NET MVC, and I had to override JSON.parse  to correctly interpret Microsoft's date format: /^\/Date\\((\d+)\\)\/$/

So that's not a problem with the grid, but it would be nice to be able to pass in Date objects.  I think the only change needed is in the parseDate function, add: if (Object.prototype.toString.call(e) === '[object Date]'){ return e; }

Thanks Oleg!