# Apply jqgrid search filter toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jqgrid

I am beginner in jqGrid and I have got 2 problems.

**Firstly**,  I want to implement a search toolbar in my grid as shown in the below image.

I have done analysis and found that  by using below line of code would enable the search toolbar. But I tried placing it, with no expect6ed output.

```
 jQuery("#overviewJqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqGridPager',
{ edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true }, {}, {}, {}, { closeAfterSearch: true });
```

[image]

**JS Code:**

```
app.controller('DiscoveryOverviewCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $compile, localStorageService) {
var gwdth = $("#divGrid").width();


    //TODO: Find a better solution
var WebApiServerUrl = $rootScope.WebApiURL;



$('#DiscoveryReportModel').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

    var reportId = button.data('id');
    var machineName = button.data('machinename');

    // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
    // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
    var modal = $(this);

    modal.find('#titleSpan').text('Machine Name / IP Address: ' + machineName)
    $("#tblDiscoveryReport").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + "/discovery/" + reportId, datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid");

    $("#tblDiscoveryReport").jqGrid({

        url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + "/discovery/" + reportId,

        datatype: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) { return JSON.stringify(postData); },
        colNames: ['Attribute Name', 'Message', 'Attribute Value'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'attributeName', width: 130 },
            { name: 'message', width: 80 },
            { name: 'attributeValue', formatter: ReportItemStatusImage, width: 40, align: 'center' }
        ],
        loadonce: true,
        width: 550,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [20, 30, 50],
        sortname: 'Attribute Name',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        sortable: true,
        mtype: 'GET',
        loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');

            if (authData) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + authData.token);
            }
            return xhr;} });

    function ReportItemStatusImage(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        if (cellvalue == true) {
            return "<img src='/assets/img/OK.png' height='16' width='16' />";
        }
        else {
            return "<img src='/assets/img/NOK.png' height='16' width='16' />";
        }
    }
});



$scope.config = {

    url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/discovery',

    datatype: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) { return JSON.stringify(postData); },
    width: gwdth,
    height: 550,
    colNames: ['ID', 'Discovery Title', 'Requested Date', 'Completed Date', 'Owner', 'Discovery Status', 'Discoverd Machines'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'id', key: true, width: 50, sorttype: 'int' },
        { name: 'discoveryTitle', width: 80 },
        { name: 'createdDateTime', width: 80, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A" } },
        { name: 'discoveryEndDate', width: 80, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A" } },
        { name: 'createdByUser', width: 80 },
        { name: 'discoveryRequestStatus', width: 80 },
        { name: 'discoverdMachinesCount', width: 80, sorttype: 'int' }
    ],

    loadonce: true,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [20, 30, 50],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    mtype: 'GET',
    subGrid: true,
    sortable: true,
    pager: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    mtype: 'GET',
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
        // we pass two parameters
        // subgrid_id is a id of the div tag created within a table
        // the row_id is the id of the row
        // If we want to pass additional parameters to the url we can use
        // the method getRowData(row_id) - which returns associative array in type name-value
        // here we can easy construct the following
        var subgrid_table_id;
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";


        pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
        $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "'></div>");

        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/discovery/' + row_id,
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ["Id", 'Machine Name / IP Address', 'Status', 'Report'],
            colModel: [
               { name: 'id', key: true, width: 50, sorttype: 'int' },
               { name: 'machineName', width: 200 },
               { name: 'isDiscovered', width: 80, edittype: 'image', formatter: isDiscoveredFormatter, align: "center", search: false },
               { name: 'id', label: 'report', formatter: reportFormatter, width: 75, fixed: true, align: 'center', search: false }
            ],
            height: '100%',
            loadonce:true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [20, 30, 50],
            sortable: true,
            sortname: 'num',
            sortorder: "asc",
            pager: pager_id,
            loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {
                var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');

                if (authData) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + authData.token);
                }
                return xhr;
            }
        });

        jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + pager_id, { edit: false, add: false, del: false })
    },
    subGridOptions: {
        // configure the icons from theme rolloer
        plusicon: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
        minusicon: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
        openicon: "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e" }, 
    loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');

        if (authData) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + authData.token);
        }
        return xhr;
    }};
var reportFormatter = function (id, cellp, rowData) {
    var stateLink = "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-link\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#DiscoveryReportModel\" data-id=\"" + id + "\" data-machinename=\"" + rowData.machineName + "\">Report</button>";
    return stateLink;
};
var isDiscoveredFormatter = function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    if (cellvalue == true)
        return '<img src="\\assets\\img\\OK.png" height="16" width="16" />';
    else
        return '<img src="\\assets\\img\\NOK.png" height="16" width="16" />';
};

//Placed here

 });
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="DiscoveryReportModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="DiscoveryReportModelLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Discovery Report</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="well with-header with-footer">
                <div class="header bordered-success">
                    <span id="titleSpan">Some title</span>
                </div>

                <div id="divReportGrid">
                    <table id="tblDiscoveryReport"></table>
                </div>                   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`<div class="row" ng-controller="DiscoveryOverviewCtrl">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header bordered-bottom bordered-themeprimary">
                <i class="widget-icon fa fa-tasks themeprimary"></i>
                <span class="widget-caption">Discovery Overview</span>
            </div>
            <div id="divGrid" class="widget-body">
                <ng-jq-grid id="overviewJqGrid" config="config" api="api"></ng-jq-grid>
                <div id="jqGridPager"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

The second Problem is that, the search tool bar on other page do not work for date field columns. It do work for 'contains' and 'does not contain' where as 'equal' and other search operations leads to blank output.

I tried using srcformats described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762645/jqgrid-filter-or-search-by-date-not-working-client-side) & referred through [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) document.

**JS Code**

```
$("#jQGridMonitoredMachines").jqGrid({
    url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getallmonitoredmachinerequests',
    datatype: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    colNames: ['Id', 'Machine Name', 'IP Address', 'Discovered Date', 'Agent Install Status', 'Agent Installation Date', 'Agent Status', 'Agent Version', 'Last HeartBeat Received'],
    colModel: [            
        { name: 'id', hidden: false, width: 20, key: true, sorttype: 'int', search: true },
        { name: 'machineName', width: 120, search: true },
        { name: 'ipAddress', width: 60, search: true },
        //{ name: 'discoveredDate', width: 110, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'y-m-d', newformat: 'l, F d, Y' } },    
        //, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','ne'], dataInit : function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({ changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, showButtonPanel: true})} } },
        { name: 'discoveredDate', width: 110, search: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A" } },
        { name: 'agentInstallStatus', width: 100, search: true },
        { name: 'agentInstallationDate', width: 110, search:true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A" } },
        { name: 'agentStatusName', width: 60, search: true },
        { name: 'agentVersion', width: 50, search: true },
        { name: 'lastHeartBeatRecieved', width: 110, search:true,formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A" } }
    ],
    rowattr: function (rd) {
        if (rd.agentInstallStatus != 'Completed' && rd.agentInstallStatus != 'Upgrade Completed' && rd.agentInstallStatus != 'Uninstallation Failed') {
            return {
                "class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"
            };
        }
    },

    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,      
    width: gwdth,
    height: 650,
    sortable:true,
    rowNum: 30,        
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    mtype: 'GET',
    multiselect: true,
    multipleSearch: true,
    pager: "#jqGridPager",
```

[image]

What I have to do more in order to get the appropriate functionality working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **When** will be executed the code `$("#overviewJqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqGridPager', ...);`? You should validate that it will be executed **after** the grid is created using to solve your first problem.
2. It's strictly recommended to use `idPrefix` for subgrid data to prevent id duplicates (for example `idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_"`).
3. it's probably more effectively to load subgrid data together with the main data
4. If `$('#DiscoveryReportModel').on('show.bs.modal', ...` could be called more as once then you should include call of `GridUnload` instead of `setGridParam`. It's important to understand that `$("#overviewJqGrid").jqGrid({...})` will convert **empty** `<table id="overviewJqGrid"></table>` to relatively complex structure of divs and tables. Thus one have two main options to refresh the data on the next call: either `setGridParam` to change some options and trigger `"reloadGrid"` or destroying previously created grid using `GridUnload` and creating new grid in the same place after that using `$("#overviewJqGrid").jqGrid({...})`. The usage of `setGridParam` before `$("#overviewJqGrid").jqGrid({...})` will not work together.

The last problem with searching for date using "equal" operation seems to me as absolutely separate problem. You use full datetime as the input data and displays there in "m/d/Y h:i:s A" format. It very uncomfortable for the user to type full date with time. The existence of milliseconds in the input data could makes additional problem. The solution could heavy depend on your exact requirements and on the fork of jqGrid which you use. I develop free jqGrid fork since about one year. I implemented *custom sorting operations*, which allows you to define exactly how you need to compare the data. You can for example compare the dates using `Date only "equal"` where you compare only the *date* part ignoring the time part. [**The old demo**](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/DatetimeSearch1.htm), which I created for [the old issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/50) demonstrates the feature. One can type (or choose) "04/15/2015" in the demo and the filtered data will be tree lines with "4/15/2015 9:15:40 PM", "4/15/2015 3:31:49 PM" and "4/15/2015 12:00:00 AM":

[image]

Finally I want to include one more reference to [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29525862/315935) which demonstrates the usage of jqGrid with respect of `directive` of anguler. Probably the example would be helpful for you too.